# BeautifulSoup4 - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' but type() returns <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is my code:

```
def getdate(game):
    date = game.tbody.tr.td
    month = date.find("span", {"class": "date-month"})
    print(type(month))
    print month.text
    print month.content
```

The variable `game` that I am passing in is:

```
<table class="table non-m" style="-webkit-user-select: auto;">
  <tbody style="-webkit-user-select: auto;">
    <tr rowgameid="R7442744" style="-webkit-user-select: auto;">

      <td style="width: 6%; -webkit-user-select: auto;">
        <span ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(item.gameDateStr)" ng-if="!isChallenge" style="-webkit-user-select: auto;">
            <div class="schedule-date" style="-webkit-user-select: auto;">
          <span class="date-month" style="-webkit-user-select: auto;">Jul</span>
            <br style="-webkit-user-select: auto;">
          <span class="date-day" style="-webkit-user-select: auto;">04</span>
            </br></div>
        </span>
      </td>

      <td class="text-center" style="width: 15%; -webkit-user-select: auto;">
        <span ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(item.gameResult)" ng-if="!isChallenge" style="-webkit-user-select: auto;">06:40PM</span>
      </td>

      <td style="width: 30%; -webkit-user-select: auto;">
        <strong style="-webkit-user-select: auto;">@</strong>
        <a href="/spa/team/09367acae6aa46cab1af2806e9730030/home" ng-href="/spa/team/09367acae6aa46cab1af2806e9730030/home" style="-webkit-user-select: auto;"><img class="img-rounded" ng-src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/file.imleagues/Images/Teams/Uploaded/201604/resized/20164290439.jpg_s.jpg" ng-style="{'background-color':initData.schoolFontTitleBack}" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/file.imleagues/Images/Teams/Uploaded/201604/resized/20164290439.jpg_s.jpg" style="width: 18px; height: 18px; -webkit-user-select: auto; background-color: rgb(5, 94, 170);"> Swift Kick in the Grass</img></a>
      </td>

      <td class="text-center" style="width: 15%; -webkit-user-select: auto;">
        <span class="text-muted" style="-webkit-user-select: auto;">
          <small style="-webkit-user-select: auto;">Outdoor Fields</small>
        </span>
          <br style="-webkit-user-select: auto;">Field 2A</br>
      </td>

      <td class="text-center" ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(item.mvps)" style="width: 30%; -webkit-user-select: auto;">
        <span class="text-muted" style="-webkit-user-select: auto;">
          <small style="-webkit-user-select: auto;">RSVP:</small>
        </span>
          <br style="-webkit-user-select: auto;">0Y | 0N | 0M</br>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can probably see I am trying to extract the month *Jul* from the code below. If I print just `month` variable on it's own I get:

```
<span class="date-month" style="-webkit-user-select: auto;">Jul</span>
```

When I try and print `month.text` or `month.content` I get the error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

This does not make sense to me as when I print `type(month)` I get:

```
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
```

What am I missing here? I have used beautifulsoup4 beforehand with code that is very similar to this and I had no problems.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Here is my main function

```
def main():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open("imlhtml.html"), "html.parser")
    games = soup.findAll("table", {"class": "table non-m"})
    # games = list(games)
    gamedata = []

    for game in games:
        print("############")
        date = getdate(game)
        time = gettime(game)
        opposition = getopposition(game)
        field = getfield(game)
        object = {
            'date': date,
            'time': time,
            'opposition': opposition,
            'field': field,
        }
        gamedata.append(object)
```

Comment: Is `game` a `BeautifulSoup` object, or just the plain HTML text?

Comment: Your code works fine for me using Python 3.5 if `game` is a `BeautifulSoup` object parsed with `lxml`. `month.text` returns `'Jul'`, while `month.contents` (note that it's contents, not content) returns `['Jul']`.

Comment: 'games = soup.findAll("table", {"class": "table non-m"})' this is how i get games. And this is how I get a game 'for game in games:' And this is how I get soup 'soup = BeautifulSoup(open("imlhtml.html"), "html.parser")'

Comment: It still works for me using `html.parser`. I'd highly recommend installing and using `lxml`, though, as it works much better with malformed HTML, and also parses other forms of XML as well. But that's not the problem here...

Comment: BTW, if you want to format text as `code` in comments, use the backtick character - `

Comment: You copied the HTML from where exactly?

Comment: Thanks, Ill format it in a sec here. And I got the code from a site called imleagues

Comment: I only copied the body of the code, does that change anything?

Comment: Also I got it from copying from the inspect element interface because view page source wouldn't show me what I needed.

Comment: Well there you go, what you saw in view page source is what you are getting, not what you see in developer tools. The content is dynamically generated

Comment: Even if I copy the code from inspect element and save it in a new file?

Comment: Well that would work bar encoding issues but not generally what i would consider scraping. Can you add the actual link?

Comment: Heres the link: http://www.imleagues.com/spa/team/591f2653d9294ba59a8f6b57f8225dc8/home You have to be logged into the site though so you cant see the actually page. Edit: And yeah its not really scraping, I'm only using this code for myself so I dont need it to access the page by itself

Comment: Did you get your code working? It all seems fine to me - aside from month.content should be month.contents. (as an aside - it's worthwhile trying to strip your problematic code down to the bare minimum - take it out of functions, take out the time and oppositions, try to get it to work on a single entity before a list etc. )

Comment: I did not, but I will give that a try today